# How to store a hashtable of lists in Python (hashed by identity)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, hashtable, python-2.x

I need to store a `set` of `list`s hashed by **identity**: two lists are equal iff they are the same object.

Not only does using `tuple`s [not make much sense semantically](http://news.e-scribe.com/397), but I also need to mutate the lists sometimes (append a few elements to the end every once in a while), so I can't use a `tuple` at all.

How do I store a hash set of lists hashed by identity in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `dict` instead of set, and let the `id` of the list be the key:

```
dct[id(lst)] = lst
```

Test for existence of list in the "set" using `id(lst) in dct`.

Comment: Mind = blown. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: How do I get back the object from the ID in the `set`? Do I need to keep track of the ID to object mappings separately?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you're using the `id`, I think you can just use a dict instead of a set.

Comment: @Mehrdad As others said, the dict *is* the mapping of ids to objects. It's important to retain the reference to the actual object somewhere in the mapping, otherwise the id could be reused if the object is garbage-collected.